# when exactly does onBatchScanResults get called

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I call:

```
bleScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
```

And I do get onScanResults.

However I never do get the onBatchScanResults, so I was wondering when does this get called. I am asking because I am worried that the function might get called in different conditions (i.e. when a lot of bluetooth devices are found).

Answer (score 4):

From my experiments, the callback onBatchScanResults(...) is called when the option reportDelay > 0
eg

```
ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setReportDelay(100)
```

Otherwise, the callback onScanResult(...) is called.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call different method to start scan.

```
startScan (List<ScanFilter> filters, 
                ScanSettings settings, 
                ScanCallback callback)
```

use `ScanSettings.Builder` to create scansetting object and set the scan mode type as `SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER`

Comment: SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER is the default anyway, so this shouldn't make a difference.